# Shared Element Transition between two fragments, keeping first fragment visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition, fragment-transitions

I got my shared element transition between two fragments working fine. However, the problem is I do not want to hide the first fragment - I want it to show underneath the newly added second fragment. If I do not include `ft.hide( firstFragment )` in my `FragmentTransaction` the shared element transition won't run.

How do I make a Shared Element Transition that keeps both fragments visible?